# Color changed (orange) for up-down vote on main site and for my avatar on meta.tex.se

Tags: discussion, design, meta, avatar

I have not understood the reason of the different color of my avatar on TeX.SE.meta and the main site as the up/down vote and other backgrounds are all colored with the color orange. Why?

[image]

Comment: @downvoters: Please why do not add your downvote considering that this is a community?

Comment: *an explanation of your downvote*

Comment: Not just you.  This is site-wide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367641/

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you very much for your advice that I not known. But instantanely, after that I have put the question, puff -2 without an explanation. Hence I vote for the closure of my question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I have had an explanation from Barbara Beeton user.